# Can I use the default Azure Microsoft certificate for client auth?

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-web-app-service, mtls

I have an Azure App Service that in some scenarios acts as a client when accessing other resources. Accessing these other resources requires client authentication via certificate.

I understand that App Service can create a certificate to use for TLS (or I can upload one) and that I can then retrieve that certificate programmatically from the App Service itself and therefore use it for client authentication. Whatever certificate I use though it cannot be self-signed and I appear to have to select a custom domain to install it for.

For a production system this is not a problem.

However, for testing we will be creating various temporary environments and having to register a domain for each of them would be highly undesirable.

What options are there for me to be able to configure multiple App Service test environments such that they use the same certificate for server and client auth but without having to register a custom domain for each environment?

The research I've done leads me to think that one possible solution would be to register a single domain for testing, then create a sub domain for each test environment, then let App Service create a free certificate for each environment. Does that work? Will App Service create a certificate for a sub domain? How does this work with deployment slots?

There are so many considerations it's making my head spin.

It seems like a lot of work. Is there any way I can just get the `*.azurewebsite.net` certificate that App Service uses by default and use that as a client certificate?